# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to initialize a GAE background thread factory

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I am trying to get the firebase databasereferece getting this error.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to initialize a GAE background thread factory

Please let me know if i am getting the database reference incorrectly.

Thanks in advance.

```
try {
        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("abcd.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                  .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
                  .setDatabaseUrl("https://abc.firebaseio.com/").build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("ERROR: FileNotFoundException :invalid service account credentials. See README.");
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: IOException : invalid service account credentials. See README.");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    DatabaseReference defaultDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using manual scaling (check your free quotas!). There are issues with the the firebase-admin-sdk in handling threads.

Docs state:

> We recommend that even Java backends use the REST API for Firebase, due to known issues with restarting App Engine threads running the Firebase Java SDK.

See here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-firebase-real-time-events-app-engine

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, rest api is a better approach.